# ld: framework not found AudioUnit

Tags: iphone, ios

I am including another project to mine and I am getting this error even when I am including all the libraries needed.

this is the error details:

```
Ld /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IMS3.app/IMS3 normal armv7
    cd /Users/alialzahrani/Desktop/IMSFolder/mydoubs/iPhone/idoubs/branches/2.0/IMS3
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -L/Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/alialzahrani/Desktop/IMSFolder/mydoubs/doubango/branches/2.0/doubango/thirdparties/iphone/lib/armv7 -F/Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Intermediates/IMS3.build/Debug-iphoneos/IMS3.build/Objects-normal/armv7/IMS3.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-link-runtime -stdlib=libc++ -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreAudio -lsqlite3 -lresolv -framework AudioToolbox -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreGraphics /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libios_ngn_stack.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyDAV.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyHTTP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyIPSec.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyMEDIA.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyMSRP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyNET.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyRTP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinySAK.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinySDP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinySIGCOMP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinySIP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinySMS.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyWRAP.a /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libtinyXCAP.a -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/alialzahrani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IMS3-ezltqoccjhjpvuakngozvwcsppvh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/IMS3.app/IMS3

ld: framework not found AudioUnit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and here is all the libraries that I did include :

[image]

and if did not include the framework I am getting 110 errors:
[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Audio Unit is just an umbrella framework, it doesn't have any actual dynamic libraries to link against, only headers. Don't add it to the project, and building will succeed. (The actual symbols for Audio Units are located in another framework, IIRC it's AudioToolbox.)

Comment: if i did not include it i am getting 101 errors,so what do you think toe solution please

Comment: @AliAlzahrani What kind of errors are you getting? I didn't told you not to include the header, I instructed you not to add the framework to the linker flags.

Comment: @AliAlzahrani those errors don't come from the AudioUnit framework. What kind of libraries are using? It seems that Speex and a few others as well.

Comment: I am trying to add this project to mine http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/wiki/Building_iDoubs_v2_x#Linking_the_ios-ngn-stack_in_your_own_app

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same error when I was creating an application of Voice recorder.

you simply do one thing, just add `AudioToolbox framework, CoreAudio framework.` in your project and also  `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>,
                    #import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>`