# XCode error: linker failed

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I saw more questions on forum but could not find appropriate answers.

```
    Ld /Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/dragonsimfull normal armv7
    cd /Users/gbnuser/Desktop/xCode_projects/DragonSim_Full_v1.0
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/gbnuser/Desktop/xCode_projects/DragonSim_Full_v1.0 -L/Users/gbnuser/Desktop/xCode_projects/DragonSim_Full_v1.0/Libraries -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/system -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/system/introspection -F/Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/dragonsimfull.LinkFileList -Xlinker -no_pie -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/dragonsimfull-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework DTPerformanceSession -framework InterfaceBuilderKit -framework SenTestingKit -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AdSupport -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioUnit -framework AVKit /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/CarrierBundleUtilities.dylib -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreAudioKit -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreTelephony /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/dylib1.o -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework GameController /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcrt1.o -framework GLKit -framework GSS -framework HealthKit -framework ImageIO -framework JavaScriptCore /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/lazydylib1.o -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MapKit -framework MediaAccessibility -framework MediaToolbox -framework MessageUI -framework Metal -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MultipeerConnectivity -framework NewsstandKit -framework NotificationCenter -framework Photos -framework PhotosUI -framework PushKit -framework QuickLook -framework SafariServices -framework SceneKit -framework Security -framework Social -framework SpriteKit -framework Twitter -framework VideoToolbox -framework WatchKit -framework WebKit -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework GameKit -weak_framework iAd -liconv.2 -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liPhone-lib -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/dragonsimfull_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/gbnuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-cdjcxjclijkdujesogrzhecyfbrp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity-iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/dragonsimfull

    ld: framework not found AudioUnit
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Did anybody already solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framework not found AudioUnit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756212/framework-not-found-audiounit)

Answer (score 0):

You may be accidentally #import'ing a .m file instead of a .h. Use Cmd+Shift+F and search for ".m" (without quotes). It will most likely lie in one of the classes mentioned in the warning. If not, clean and run again.

/////////////////////////

or

This error may be because of some missing libraries in your project.

Check in your Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. Any of your framework may had been removed from there.

Add it and Clean and Build your project. It should work fine.

Hope it helps you.